# The "Hartree-Fock energy" in the Feynman formalism vs the Hartree-Fock method

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, ground-state, mean-field-theory

This question has been [previously asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43285/feynman-diagrams-and-hartree-fock), but I do not understand the answer.

When calculating the ground state energy of an interacting system by a perturbative expansion in terms of Feynman diagrams, say for the interacting electron gas, the contribution of the first-order diagrams is often referred to as the "Hartree-Fock energy" (see Nolting, just under equation 5.139, or Section 43.2 in Lancaster & Blundell).

I am conceptually familiar with the Hartree-Fock method for finding ground states of interacting systems by assuming that the quantum state can be written as a single Slater determinant, then iteratively solving for the right set of basis wavefunctions.

Am I missing some kind of deeper connection here? The answer to the linked questions seems to suggest that one can rederive the Hartree-Fock method by summing diagrams at all orders (via the self-energy), which of course involves going beyond first order. But then I don't understand why the first-order contribution is called the Hartree-Fock energy, if the connection involves going beyond first order. Is this just an unfortunate naming convention?

For context: I am interested in computing the ground state energy for a system of fermions interacting by s-wave scattering (so the pair interaction is a delta function). I computed the two first-order Feynman diagrams, and found that they cancelled out. Obviously, I know that there should be some energy change to the ground state associated with adding an interaction, so I don't see how the contributions of first-order Feynman diagrams could possibly be equivalent to Hartree-Fock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual in physics, one term can mean a lot of things, depending on the community. In the field theoretic part of condensed matter theory (more interested in models like the jellium, superconductivity, etc.), the HF correction is the first (non-self-consistent) correction to the free electron gas to the energy and to the self-energy (corresponding to the tadpole and "oyster" diagram of Lancaster & Blundell).
(Side note: in QFT, one should always work with the self-energy to compute correction to the propagator. So a first order term in the self-energy is indeed amounts to sum an infinite number of terms in the propagator, but still counts as a first order correction).

The self-energy is a functional of $G_0$, $\Sigma[G_0]$, which is not self-consistent since $G_0$ is the free propagator, which is approximated in the HF approximation by two diagrams (that we give a contribution that we call $\Sigma_{HF}[G_0]$.

In the quantum chemistry / material physics part of the community, the HF theory is usually a self-consistent theory for the propagator, which is written in terms of orbitals, and is thus different from what is explained above.

However, one can reconciliate the two approach by making the equation for the HF self-energy self-consistent, i.e. $\Sigma_{HF}[G_0]\to\Sigma_{HF}[G]$. This is now a more complicated equation, since $G=G_0-G_0\Sigma_{HF}[G]G$ cannot be solved easily. However, writing $G(x,y)$ in a matrix form in terms of eigenvalues (corresponding roughly to the inverse of the energy of each orbitals) and eigenvectors (corresponding to the orbitals), one should recover the standard HF equation of quantum chemistry.
In the jargon of QFT, this method corresponds to work to the lowest order approximation of the Luttinger-Ward functional in the 2 Particle Irreducible formalism.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it should be stressed that there are no two different approaches going by the name 'Hartee-Fock': HF *always* refers to a self-consistent procedure. It just happens to reduce to a simple first-order perturbative calculation for translationally invariant systems, like the uniform electron gas or nuclear matter (as shown in Mattuck or Fetter & Walecka).

Comment: @dennismoore94 your comment is self-contradictory... HF cannot be at the same time "self-consistent" and "reduce to simple first-order perturbative calculation for translationally invariant systems", since the latter is not self-consistent.

Comment: If the one-particle basis associated with the zeroth order (non-interacting) solution is made of plane waves (which is the case when no external potential is present, that is, the system is translationally invariant) then the plane waves actually solve the self-consistent HF equations. As a consequence, the HF energy $E=\langle\Phi|H|\Phi\rangle$ (where the determinant $|\Phi\rangle$ is built from the orbitals solving the HF equations) does reduce to the first order energy (considering a perturbation theory built on the fully non-interacting system). Also, in the lack...

Comment: ...of external potential, the self-consistent HF Green's function calculation introduces lots of vanishing anomalous diagrams, and you end up with the usual geometric sum (a la Dyson equation). So, in this case, it makes no difference whether you use the non-interacting propagator or the dressed HF propagator in the self-energy parts. What you see as a "different method curiously also named Hartree-Fock" is just the usual self-consistent Hartree-Fock applied to a special system.

Comment: @dennismoore94 We are probably not talking about the same things (or at least, I don't understand what you are talking about). For translation invariant system, computing $\Simga[G_0]$ at the 1-loop level is not self-consistent and called Hartree-Fock. But for the same system, solving $\Sigma[G]$ (with the same functional $\Sigma$) is self-consistent, but it will definitely not give the same result.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, my point is exactly that $\Sigma_{\text{HF}}[G_0]$ and $\Sigma_{\text{HF}}[G_{\text{HF}}]$ are equal when no external potential is present ($\Sigma_{\text{HF}}$ being the usual "tadpole + open oyster" functional). There are two ways to see this. One way is to note that for such systems, the orbitals of the non-interacting system are also the HF orbitals (solutions of the HF equations), and then substitute them in $\Sigma_{\text{HF}}$; this is carried out at the end of Sec. 10 of Fetter & Walecka. The other way is to iterate graphically the Dyson...

Comment: ...equation $G_{\text{HF}}=G_0+G_0\Sigma_{\text{HF}}[G_{\text{HF}}]G_{\text{HF}}$, and realize that all of the extra diagrams $\Sigma_{\text{HF}}[G_{\text{HF}}]$ generates (compared to $\Sigma_{\text{HF}}[G_0]$) are such that a particle ($k>k_{\text{F}}$) and a hole ($k<k_{\text{F}}$) line carry the same momentum, which cannot be (interactions are momentum-conserving due to uniformity). So, Hartree-Fock truly reduces to a first-order calculation in this case, and there are no two different Hartree-Fock methods.

Comment: @dennismoore94 I disagree, they are not the same. I'll take the example of bosons with contact interaction $g$ above the BEC transition. The HF self-energy reads $\Sigma[G]=2 g \int_K G(K)$ where $K$ represents both Matsubara frequencies and momenta. The 1-loop (not self-consistent HF) propagator reads $G_1(K)=1/(i\omega -\epsilon_k+\mu-2g n_0)$, with $n_0$ the density of the non-interacting system: $n_0=\int_k n_{BE}(\epsilon_k-\mu)$. The self-consistent HF solution gives the self-energy $2g n$, where $n$ is the self-consistent solution to $n=\int_k n_{BE}(\epsilon_k-\mu+2gn)$

Comment: The source of our disagreement seems to be that you're talking about a finite temperature formalism, while I'm talking about zero temperature (and I think this is what OP had in mind too, since they mentioned a single Slater determinant). For $T>0$, you are right, the two methods are not the same, but they are for $T=0$ when applied to a uniform system (maybe I should have emphasized that when saying uniform system, I'm meaning symmetric HF solutions, not the broken symmetry ones). Anyway, I think I got us a bit sidetracked. My only issue with your (otherwise really good)...

Comment: ...answer was that I feel only the SC method should be called HF (if nothing else, for historical reasons). After your example, I started looking into the literature, and I see that it is indeed not entirely consistent; in some papers/books people do talk about SC HF and non-SC HF (one-loop SE), while other books (e.g. Fetter & Walecka) strictly reserve the name HF for the SC calculation (at both $T=0$ and $T>0$). This weird branching might stem from the early days: the first extended systems investigated with QFT methods were uniform systems at $T=0$, for which the two methods coincide.

Comment: @dennismoore94 ok, I think I agree with you. And you are probably right that HF theory is usually self-consistent (also the use is not consistent across the literature). In fact, I've just remembered that in bosonic system, the only difference between the Bogoliubov and HF-Bogoliubov theory is that the latter is self-consistent

Comment: Thank you for the discussion! Following the bosonic example, I learned quite a few new things about finite temperature HF.